# How to use pivot function, using datepart fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, pivot

> Current Output

`WeekNumber WeeklyCount
      11      100
      10      200
       9      300
       8      400
       7      500`

> Desired Output

```
WeekNumber   11  10   9   8   7
WeeklyCount 100 200 300 400 500
```

> Current query:

```
SELECT Top 5     DatePart(ww, DATE) as weekNumber, Count(id) as WeeklyCount
    FROM         dbo.AL
   Where DatePart(ww, DATE) <> DatePart(ww, GetDate())
    group by  DatePart(ww, DATE)
    order by DatePart(ww, DATE) desc
```

> How do I use the pivot function to return the desired output?

```
Pivot function query
```

Comment: If you know about pivot why dont you try something?There are a lot of examples on the web

Comment: I've tried many times with no success, I am assuming pivot is the answer...

Comment: http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT [11], [10], [9], [8], [7]
FROM (YourQueryHERE) AS DT
PIVOT(SUM(WeeklyCount) FOR WeekNumber IN([11], [10], [9], [8], [7])) AS PT
```

If you want dynamic version, please see my comment ;)

Comment: That works. I will have to look into the dynamic pivot. Thank you